# PHP / Wordpress / Automatic news

Tags: php, wordpress, blogs

I want to ask for advice in solving one non-standard problem.

There is a server on which the program written in C ++ is twisted (there are source codes and it can be modified at will). This program generates news as a text file. News is not generated regularly, that is, the time of creating a new file with news is not known in advance.

Also on the server there is a website on wordpress. News should appear in the form of new posts in the standard blog. Now a person checks once a day whether a news file was generated and manually adds them to the site. I would like to automate this process.

I started by looking for suitable plugins for Wordpress, but I could not find anything suitable. Friends have suggested that you need to modify the PHP code of WordPress. Since I absolutely do not understand anything in PHP, I ask you to indicate in which direction to move. Maybe someone has already encountered a similar problem and could share a couple of links to materials on PHP that will help solve the problem.

Comment: ignore friends - never modify core framework code - as soon as an update comes along, your updated code is rerwritten

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out you should never modify core WordPress code, as this will cause your changes to be overwritten the next time WordPress updates.

This is the purpose of plugins, as they allow you to add functionality to the core WordPress offering without conflicting with the upstream development. If you can not find a plugin to do this that is already available, you may need to write one yourself.

However, since you say you are not familiar with PHP you should consider learning more about the language first, and then referencing the official WordPress documentation on writing plugins: https://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin